# c++ sync_with_stdio performance

Tags: c++, stream

It is said here http://en.cppreference.com/ that "*If the synchronization is turned off, the C++ standard streams are allowed to buffer their I/O independently, which may be considerably faster in **some cases***."

What are those cases ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the be synchronized you should use `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(bool)` which guarantee you that buffers among the I/O libs will be synchronized. This should be called before any I/O.

Answer (score 0):

From some tests it seems that there is a significant performance penalty for *synchronized* output. The cases we have been seeing this is GCC and relatively small volume I/O from stdin/ to stdout (reading / printing individual int, float, char* variables).

Obviously, non-synchronized situation - up to a few hundred times faster (I don't remember the exact values, and it varied).